# C# code breaks after this for cycle

Tags: c#, for-loop, break

I have this following for cycle:

```
string[] sfind = new string[Globais.dep.Length];
int udt = 0;
for (int getnum = 0; getnum <= Globais.dep.Length; getnum++)
{
    if (Globais.dep[getnum].Contains(items[1]))
    {
        sfind[udt] = Globais.dep[getnum];
        udt ++;
    }
}
```

I have more code following this cycle, but I watched it with debugger and it doesn't run the code below, after the for cycle ends it breaks the whole code. What am I doing wrong here? I don't see whats the problem with the cycle.

Regardless, Thanks!

Comment: What means "it breaks the whole code"?

Comment: How does it "break the whole code"?  In what way does it actually fail?

Comment: It doesnt run the code bellow @TimSchmelter

Comment: The problem is "getnum <= Globais.dep.Length" - an array is 0 to Length-1.

Comment: Include "the code below" in your post.

Comment: @David thats what im trying to figure out, the cycle does what i want but when it ends it breaks for whatever reason...

Comment: @jeyejow Does it throw an error? Because if not the code below it should at least be entered in debugger and maybe crash there

Comment: The fact that you didn't realise that it was throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` points to a wider issue with your code - you have error "handling" somewhere that is *actively hiding errors from you*.

Comment: Well, im still learning how to code, so sorry if simple mistakes annoys you guys.

Comment: Not annoyed. Just pointing out that you've probably already picked up a bad habit - if you have, for instance, any *empty* `catch` blocks, or `catch` blocks that just write the exception details to somewhere obscure and then do nothing else, those things are *hindering* you, not helping.

Comment: ohh i see, well i only program for about some months, i still have alot to learn, but ill pay attention to that :O @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List or array indexers start at 0 and end at length-1, but you are using `getnum <= Globais.dep.Length` , use `<` instead of `<=`:

```
for (int getnum = 0; getnum < Globais.dep.Length; getnum++)
{
  // ...
}
```

Side-note: your code caused an `IndexOutOfRangeException` which you either have noticed, then you should have mentioned it in the question, or not, then something is hiding it like an empty `try...catch` which is normally a bad idea.

Comment: Oh snap! I completly forgot that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can use foreach loop like below

```
if(Globais.dep.Length > 0)
{
  string[] sfind = new string[Globais.dep.Length];
  foreach (string str in Globais.dep)
     {
        if (str.Contains(items[1]))
        {
           sfind[str]
        }
     }
}
```